# Looping through a series of columns and plotting them using subplots in a grid fashion (columns and rows)

Tags: loops

Newbie here, So the code below is what I currently have that works. However, it's not the most convenient way when you have a lot of columns to plot. I'm trying to loop through 10 columns while maintaining a grid subplots layout of 2 rows and 5 columns for the distplots.

See link for screenshot of 3 different attempts to do this with no success. Any help will be appreciated. [failed attempts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwW6V.jpg)

Here's the code (below) I'd like to simplify by looping through columns:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols = 5, nrows = 2, figsize = (30, 10))
    
sns.distplot(df['col_1'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[0,0])  
sns.distplot(df['col_2'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[0,1])  
sns.distplot(df['col_3'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[0,2])
sns.distplot(df['col_4'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[0,3])
sns.distplot(df['col_5'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[0,4]) 
sns.distplot(df['col_6'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[1,0])
sns.distplot(df['col_7'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[1,1])  
sns.distplot(df['col_8'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[1,2])   
sns.distplot(df['col_9'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[1,3])
sns.distplot(df['col_10'], color='green', kde=True, ax = axs[1,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found a solution to my problem above. Here's how it goes...

```
cols = ['LF','LF_PCT','LF_NU','VLF','VLF_PCT','HF','HF_PCT','HF_NU','HF_LF','TP']
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=5, nrows=2, figsize = (30, 10))    
ax = np.ravel(axs)
for count, i in enumerate(cols):
    sns.distplot(df[i], color='green', kde=True, ax=ax[count])
```